# SharedPreferences structure and ovoid user clear this

Tags: java, android, xml, security, sharedpreferences

I save some value in SharedPreferences. I know this is a xml file, that are sandboxed to prevent other applications from being able to access the values.

1. I want to know a structure of SharedPreferences, or just like a original xml file?
   All SharedPreferences will be save in only 1 xml file?
2. User can clear data of application, that mean all of my SharedPreferences will gone. How can i protect my saved information?

Regards

Comment: There isn't a good reason to save data from Shared Preferences. That is the whole point of the xml file being deleted when the app is removed. You're only option is to write to persistent storage. Doing that will make your data public.

Comment: i want still have data when user clean my app data in Setting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes SharedPreferences is an xml file. But it doesnt have to be one xml file you can vary this like `SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("options.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);`
2. If user clear application data no data will left about application.

Comment: How some trial app can count down the Expiration date? If user clear data, they can use this app many time?

Comment: I think for a trial app you should use a server-like structure to hold datas of the devices ids which use this app. Every use of the application you can check the time the application installed on the server.

Comment: but may be they are offline app

Comment: then you force user to have internet once application started.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can grab the xml from /data/data/"package name"/prefs/
   The preference file names how you named it with [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

2) Clear data has intent to clear data. You shall not protect user saved information from clearing. You may protect by putting some settings to sdcard. But please do not do that for user data.

Comment: i want to save user token, SRA private key.